# Java txt file as database

Tags: java, database

I am trying to use a text file as a database and I came across a problem. The problem is when I write the user info on the text file, it doesn't write to the next line when I add a second user. It just overwrites the old one. How can I add a writeToNextLine kind of thing?

```
public void addAdmin(String adminName, String adminSurName, String adminUserName, String adminPassword) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\cemon\\IdeaProjects\\Library\\src\\database\\AdminUserData.txt"));
    writer.write(adminName + " " + adminSurName);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write(adminUserName + " " + adminPassword);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Hint: look at the `FileWriter` constructor overloads.

Comment: Sir, I found these but I didn't understand what you meant to say. Could you please explain it to me? And also isn't there a way that it doesn't create a new file every time.I don't want my data to be lost every time I close a program

Comment: FileWriter(String file) Creates a new file. It gets file name in string.
FileWriter(File file) Creates a new file. It gets file name in File object.

Comment: FileWriter(File file, boolean append) Sir is this the one i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enable `append` mode in the `FileWriter`. This means that when you write a new line, instead of overwriting, it adds another line.

Your code should be:

```
public void addAdmin(String adminName, String adminSurName, String adminUserName, String adminPassword) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\cemon\\IdeaProjects\\Library\\src\\database\\AdminUserData.txt", true));
    writer.write(adminName + " " + adminSurName);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write(adminUserName + " " + adminPassword);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Bad idea. How do you know you're not adding a duplicate user?

If you want a simple text file as a database, load the text file into memory on startup, e.g. as a `Map<String, User>` keyed by `adminUserName`, and add a new user there. Whenever a value changes, write all the users back to the text file.

That also ensures that (future) operations like "remove user" will work correctly.

Recommend implementing a `UserStore` class with the suggested `Map` as a field, to keep the implementation hidden (encapsulated) from the rest of your program.

Comment: I have validations sir

Comment: public boolean isUserNameTaken() {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\cemon\\IdeaProjects\\Library\\src\\database\\CivilianUserData.txt");
        try{
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
            while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                if(reader.nextLine().substring(0,userName.getText().length() + 1).equals(userName.getText())){
                    return true;

                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }

Comment: I have never used Map before, I don't even know what it is or how it works, thank you for your suggestion.I need to do some research about what you said.I'm fairly new

Comment: This is the way i implements for test users sometime, when big sql database is an overkill!